# can't make migration in laravel by php artisan migrate command

Tags: laravel

when i write this command: 
php artisan migrate

[image]
Laravel Provides Database migrations which don't work very well for me  when i write this command: 
php artisan migrate
 it always give me this error

Comment: it seems you are not able to connect the database, are you sure the credentials right

Comment: Please include error messages as text rather than images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: the error is :        SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ecom_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: The error says that PHP can’t connect to the MySQL instance.It your database credential are correct, then clear your config cache `php artisan config:cache` then run again `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Change the  **.env** file from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` fixed it.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

do config:cache after .env file change. `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Ensure your configuration is right. or have you config:cache?

Comment: Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!

Comment: Have you got the solutions?

Comment: Select the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have an .env file, and that the database related variables within have been set correctly.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_database_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_database_password
```